# Copying Excel data from multiple worksheets into one single sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried searching the internet for various answers to this question but cannot find the right answer. I have an Excel Workbook with worksheets represent each day of the month. In each of these sheets the format is the same (except on Saturdays and Sundays) and the sheets contain call stats. It is presented in the following format:

00:00   00:30    **0    4    6    3    4    8    0    1    0    0    0**


00:00   00:30    **0    0    2    7    4    1    0    0    3    3    0**


00:00   00:30    **7    0    7    5    2    8    6    1    7    9    0**

I need to copy this data into 1 single sheet that lists all the data. Basically it appends the new data  on to the bottom of the old data. So it will be one big list.

How can this be done? All I can see is how to produce a total from multiple data by adding all the values together. I just need to list the data as one big list.

Comment: You want to combine all the data into one NEW worksheet, correct? Also, the format you shown, how many columns are there?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Obviously, you missed a few search hits. ;) Try checking this [out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992962/how-to-paste-at-the-next-empty-cell-instead-of-pasting-at-the-same-cell/19994483#19994483]).

Comment: There are 47 rows and 13 columns for the Monday to Friday entries, there are 7 rows and 13 columns on a Saturday entry and 8 rows and 13 columns on a sunday entry. The sheets are labeled as "01 November 2012" right up to the last date of the month so the only way to determine the day of the month is by its corresponding date and how many columns are in the data.

Comment: Thank you BK201. However my understanding of VBA code is low. I can understand Java and its structure but VBA is just a whole different level!

Comment: That's alright. I'll try to have a go at it. Mind you, Java is way harder than VBA. ;) Anyway, to the code: Do you need each of the data sets to be copied to a single sheet? What is the name of this summary sheet and do you need each line copied to have a day-name or a date-name before it? Like, `Sunday 00:00:00 etc etc bang bang`? Also, do you have headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MASSIVE EDIT:**

As with last chat with Iain, the correct parameters have been set. I have removed the last few code snippets as they are quite not right. If anyone is still interested, please check the edit history.

Hopefully, this is the final edit. ;)

So, the correct conditions needed are:

1. Month name in sheet. We used an Input Box for this.
2. We check for number of rows. There are three conditions: 157 rows total, 41 rows total, and all else.

The following subroutine will do the trick.

```
Sub BlackwoodTransfer()

    Dim Summ As Worksheet, Ws As Worksheet
    Dim ShName As String
    Dim nRow As Long

    Set Summ = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
    ShName = InputBox("Enter month for Call Flow in mmmm format (ie. November, etc.):") & " Call Flow"
    'Returns November Call Flow. This means it will target every sheet that has November Call Flow in its name.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, Ws.Name, ShName) > 0 Then
        'Starting from first character of the sheet's name, if it has November, then...
            nRow = Summ.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            '... get the next empty row of the Summary sheet...
            Select Case Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            '... check how many rows this qualified sheet has...
                Case 157
                '... if there are 157 rows total...
                    Ws.Range(Cells(57,1),Cells(104,13)).Copy
                    '... copy Rows 57 to 104, 13 columns wide...
                    Summ.Range("A" & nRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                    '... and paste to next empty row in Summary sheet.
                Case 41
                    Ws.Range(Cells(23,1),Cells(126,13)).Copy
                    Summ.Range("A" & nRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll               
                Case Else
                    Ws.Range(Cells(23,1),Cells(30,13)).Copy
                    Summ.Range("A" & nRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            End Select
        End If
    Next Ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

@Iain: Check out the comments and cross reference them with the MSDN database. That should explain what each function/method is doing exactly. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write the code for me. When I run it I get a syntax error on the following line: If WS.Name <> Summ.Name

Comment: @IainBlackwood: Edited. Just forgot the `Then` in the `If` line. Sorry, just pulled out Notepad for that one. ;)

Comment: No no don't be sorry, you are helping me... no need to be sorry! I re-edited your code but now I get Object variable or With block variable not set. I am right in saying that I should have a Summ worksheet in my workbook?

Comment: @IainBlackwood: Edited again. `With block` error is because there was an `End With` line without any `With` preceding it. Check it now. And yes, you need to have a sheet named "Summary". Check Huy's approach as well.

Comment: Ran it and I was greeted with pasted results in my Summary sheet! So thank you for that. I am working my way through the code to try and understand what it means.

However I should have mentioned... there are some sheets at the beginning I would like to exclude as they contain no date I need. Also it seems that this code is copying all of the data within the sheets, where I only need it to copy certain rows and columns. Although what you have done for me is bloody fantastic :)

Comment: That's alright. :) So basically the name of the sheets you have are "01 November 2012", "02 November 2012", etc? Just noticed though, that this might be for 2013 and not 2012. Reason is, if this is 2013, you have to run this every day, yes? If it's 2012, then I can create a macro that takes any month and year and combines them. Let me know if this is for current data or 'already-completed' data. :)

Comment: It will be used at the end of the month for the user to run the macro and get all the data in one big list that feeds a chart. There are a few sheets at the beginning of the work book though that are not needed (6 to be exact). I just mentioned that it was November 2012 as I didn't want someone to obviously point out that the month was not over :P

Comment: Added a variable solution. It's untested as I only have Notepad for the time being. But it should work.

Comment: Ok I have been working through the code, trying to understand it. It works great for one spreadsheet, however it doesn't seem to cycle through them all. Is there a loop in the code? I am used to If, Then, Else loops with Java but it seems VBA uses a different method here? I am so confused

Comment: Sorry, I meant worksheet. Not spreadsheet. It doesnt go through all the worksheets. My apologies

Comment: What a nightmare. Ok it does go through the worksheets, I was just being an eejit. The naming convention of the Sheets look like this: 01 November Call Flow, 02 November Call Flow and so forth. So I changed 2 sheets to Nov 2013 and hence the confusion. Would I have to change the line ShName = (InputBox("Enter the month and year in mmmm yyyy format (ex. Nov 2012):")) to match this

Comment: Hello, Iain. Sorry, on mobile. Basically, you can opt to remove the `yyyy` part in the `mmmm yyyy` part, leaving just `mmmm`. You can change the message in the input box but that's just for flavor. :)

Comment: My apologies too, I am at work and testing it out there, so between doing other things I am testing the code and making mistakes which are my own! I have managed to get it working thank you :) this has helped a lot. I am going to go through the code and try to make sense of it all. Shouldn't be too hard I hope!!

Comment: Taking into consideration the proper sheet names, I'll do one final edit and then let's move this discussion to chat if there are any more issues. ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41532/discussion-between-iain-blackwood-and-bk201)

Comment: This was the perfect answer! Thank you :)

Comment: No worries. :) Thanks for accepting. Read through the comments. VBA is way easier than Java. ;)

Comment: @TheLaughingMan : So basically I spent last 90 minutes helping my sister with her homework through the facebook messenger using the code you wrote after chatting with Iain on SO chat... also I haven't got MS Office on my PC. Yay!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub CombineSheets()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, wsCombine As Worksheet
   Dim rg As Range
   Dim RowCombine As Integer

   Set wsCombine = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1))
   wsCombine.Name = "Combine"

   RowCombine = 1
   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      If ws.Index <> 1 Then
         Set rg = ws.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
         rg.Copy wsCombine.Cells(RowCombine, 2)
         wsCombine.Range(Cells(RowCombine, 1), Cells(RowCombine + rg.Rows.Count - 1, 1)) = ws.Name
         RowCombine = RowCombine + rg.Rows.Count
      End If
   Next
   wsCombine.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.AutoFit
   Set rg = Nothing
   Set wsCombine = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a worksheet "Summary" which is to contain all the merged data.
Open ThisWorkBook (simply press ALT+F11 in your excel workbook. A new window will open. Your worksheet name will be visible on the left hand side. Keep expanding till you see ThisWorkBook)
Double click ThisWorkBook and add the following code in it:

```
Sub SummurizeSheets() 
    Dim ws As Worksheet 

    Application.Screenupdating = False 
    Sheets("Summary").Activate 

    For Each ws In Worksheets 
        If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then 
            ws.Range("F46:O47").Copy 
            ActiveSheet.Paste Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 
        End If 
    Next ws 
End Sub
```

Comment: While this is an easy way, this won't work with varying lengths of data. Also won't work that well with Excel 2010 as you are using `A65536` as a reference row to use `End(xlUp)` on. A better way is to use `Cells(Rows.Count, 1)` or the like to accommodate version differences. :)

Comment: I agree. Your answer is much better. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub AddToMaster()
'this macro goes IN the master workbook
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, wbDATA As Workbook
Dim NextRow As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim n As Long
Dim i


Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Specify the folder path

FolderPath = "D:\work\"

'specifying file name

 FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")

Do While FileName <> ""

NextRow = wsMaster.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Set wbDATA = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

    With wbDATA.Sheets("product_details")
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
       ' If LastRow > 5 Then
        For i = 2 To LastRow

            .Range("A2:j" & i).Copy
            wsMaster.Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            'Set NextRow = NextRow
        Next i
    End With
  FileName = Dir()
    Loop

wbDATA.Close False
End Sub
```