# Reading from Excel dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I'm not sure if using the word "dynamic" is correct. Anyway, I do have some basic understanding of using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. The problem is, I'm having about 100 excel files in a folder, each of the excel files has different `sheet name, number of rows and number of columns`.

As far as I understand, you need to specify the `range` and `sheet` name, i.e.:

```
xcel.Worksheet sheet = someExcelFiles.Sheets["SomeSheetName"] as Excel.Worksheet;

Excel.Range range = sheet.get_Range("A1:A5");
```

Is there anyway so that my application can read all data in all of the excel files without having to specify the `sheet name` and `range` (row and columns)?

Comment: No. Longer answer: Yes.  You would have to cycle through each sheet in each workbook and read the used range of each sheet.

Comment: Unless I'm forgetting something, you should be able to just iterate over the `Sheets` collection (`foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in someExcelFiles.Sheets)`) and use the `sheet.Cells.get_Value` method to get all cell values as a 2D array (`object[,]`).

Comment: @Ginosaji Let me research around a little bit, this is my second time reading an excel in C# so I'm still not good at it.

Comment: Here is a similar problem w/ solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20066549/2258

Comment: Also try using a number instead of the name of the sheet. If that works (I believe it will) keep in mind the array index starts at 1, not at 0 as normal C# arrays do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer yes. Long answer From [DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel) which also contains grabbing number of sheets programatically.

```
Range excelRange = sheet.UsedRange;
object[,] valueArray = (object[,])excelRange.get_Value(
    XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
```