# Pasting two similar tables with different and variable amount of data

Tags: vba, excel

My problem is that I have two tables (with the exact same format, headings and everything but with different amount of data and it can change over time) in two different worksheets. How can I unify them in a new worksheet (paste one of them above the other). I would like a macro to do this so I can avoid manual pasting. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying Excel data from multiple worksheets into one single sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066005/copying-excel-data-from-multiple-worksheets-into-one-single-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a macro you might want to consider referencing. For this, the number of cells in each table must be defined. Let's say you have 100 rows in table 1 (sheet 1) and 100 rows in table 2 (sheet 2).
A101 (in sheet1) = Sheet2!A1 and drag that formula for the next 100 rows. Good luck.